# MySQL. Как использовать условия в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста как использовать условия в SQL запросе?

Есть столбец Cat, в нем в строках числа через запятую.

Допустим есть строка с значением  1,2,10,3,4

Мне надо найти ее по числу 10 и заменить цифры 1,2,3,4 на 5,6,7,8

То есть условие должно быть примерно так:

```
Если cat like 10, то заменяем
1 = > 5
2 = > 6
3 = > 7
4 = > 8
```

Не работал никогда с условиями, помогите пожалуйста с решением..

Спасибо всем заранее!

Comment: Хранить числа через запятую не очень хорошо, лучше сделать связь один ко многим

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, у вас только цифры или числа? И может ли встретиться 100, например?

Comment: Может 100 встретится(

Comment: Текстовое поле в нем данные как я написал. В таком формате

Comment: @Nick да у него и сразу там десятка затесалась - так себе цифра...

Comment: На показанной структуре данных замена в один запрос, конечно, возможна - но это будет жуткий монстр, причём совершенно несопровождаемый, переделываемый для каждого набора пар для замены, и распухающий с увеличением количества таких пар. Нормализуйте данные. Или выполняйте требуемую операцию в формате хранимой процедуры либо пользовательской функции.

Answer (score 0):

Если нельзя изменить структуру данных и нельзя сделать не средствами бд и без хранимых процедур то вот Ваш монстр:

```
update tbl set cat = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', cat, ','), ',1,', ',5,'), ',2,', ',6,'), ',3,', ',7,'), ',4,', ',8,') ) where CONCAT(',', cat, ',') LIKE '%,10,%';
```